# How to get images on full screen in navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, image, navigation-drawer, fullscreen

Help please.
When I click on the image in navigation drawer, I want the image to be full screen.

Does anyone know how to do that?
Is there a special kind of code?

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Or what documentation you have researched?

Comment: I tried some codes but the image  doesn't come out of navigation drawer so I don't have anything in particular jet. This is the first place I aksed about it.
Do you know anything about it?